# Moving the CV header up

Tags: cv

I am learning creating custom class files by doing class file for CV. In the following example, I tried to move the CV header (i.e., name and contact) up with the command `\vspace{}`. But only the contact moves up not the name. How can I move both of them up? Here is `cv.tex`

```
\documentclass{my_cv} 
\begin{document}

    \name{\vspace{-2cm}John Smith}

    \contact{\vspace{-1cm}123 Broadway}{London}{UK 12345}{\faLinkedin {}{}  john@smith.com}{(000)-111-1111}

    \section{Education}
    \datedsubsection{University of Nowhere}{2004-2008}

    \section{Work}
    \datedsubsection{ABC Limited}{2008-Now}
    \workitems
    {Developed new product}
    {Improved productivity by 20\%}
    {Decreased costs by \$10,000}

    \section{Skills}

    \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
        C\# & T-SQL & Javascript & HTML \\
        XML & JSON & SOAP & REST
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And here is `my_cv.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{my_cv}[6/6/2013 custom CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\scshape\raggedright}
{}{0em}
{}
[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\large\scshape\raggedright}
{}{0em}
{}

\newcommand{\datedsection}[2]{
    \section[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}
}
\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{
    \subsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}
}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{
    \centerline{\Huge{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\contact}[5]{
    #1 {\large\textperiodcentered} #2 {\large\textperiodcentered} #3
    {\Large} #4 \ {\Large} #5
}

\newcommand{\longcontact}[5]{
    \center{#1 \hfill {\large\textperiodcentered} \hfill #2 \hfill {\large\textperiodcentered} \hfill #3}
    \center{ {\Large} #4 \hfill {\Large} #5}
}

\newcommand{\workitems}[3]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item #1
        \item #2
        \item #3
    \end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using vspace in those macros anyway, the layout should be defined in the class, and `\name`/`\contact` should only contain information, no formatting instructions. Why don't you set the margins with e.g. `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   top=2cm,
   textwidth=345pt
}` (345pt is the default text width in `article`).

Comment: Is there any news here?